# My jQuery scripts work when access the file, but not as a intranet site

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iis-7

Issue - When I access my page \\server\d$\Intranet\Homepage.htm everything works. No issues.  When I access has a homepage, "http://server/intranet/homepage.htm"(intranet not a website) no scripts work.  The page/scripts work on every pc, so it isn't a broswer issue.

linked code -

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" > <!--Added to see if compatiblity was the issue-->
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <!--css works-->
<link href="css/vader/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scripts" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

It isn't a conflict with two versions (I've removed the 1.8.21 and still is broken).  Everything I've read says IIS doesn't limit it just serves, but I'm not sure.  I'm just getting started with IIS, jQuery and coding in general. Any help is greatly needed and appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried debugging with a developer console?

Comment: my first thought is that it's a relative path issue

Comment: The fact you have relative URLs is a big red flag for me.

Comment: FYI - those aren't two versions of jquery. One is jquery and one is jquery-ui.

Comment: try to accesss the js files with absolute path and see if it works? like `http://server/intranet/js/jquery.scripts`

Comment: Check directory permissions for the directory and IIS. That is my only guess.

Comment: Sometimes, local will read all the files, but through the web server will cache. Try to clear your cache every time you make a change.

Answer (score 0):

This is most commonly a security issue. Try enabling the intranet sites or adding the domain to the trusted sites on your browser.

Here are some resuurces to help you:

- http://www.slickit.ca/2009/02/internet-explorer-enable-intranet.html
- http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Changing-intranet-security-settings

The first link should do the trick:

> Control Pannel > Internet Options > Security > Local Intranet > Sites > Uncheck Automatically detect intranet network > OK > OK